# array_walk only partially removes matches

Tags: php, lambda, reduction, array-walk

Ran into a weird situation were using [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) will only partially remove matches from my method, not certain exactly what is going on. I am currently using PHP v5.6.4. The issue almost seems to be that it is only removing every secondary match.

The kerning function

```
private function strip(array $exceptions)
{
    array_walk($this->hosts, function($v, $k) USE ($exceptions)
    {
        foreach ($exceptions AS $exception)
        {
            if (preg_match("/{$exception}/i", strtolower($k)))
            {
                unset($this->hosts[$k]); break;
            }
        }
    });
    print_r($this->hosts); die;
}
```

Comment: Why not use array_filter() instead?

Comment: array_filter() is fine as well, this was just the way I knew how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

> Only the values of the array may potentially be changed; its structure cannot be altered, i.e., **the programmer cannot add, unset or reorder elements**. If the callback does not respect this requirement, the behavior of this function is undefined, and unpredictable.

my emphasis

Comment: Agreed, the array_filter implementation doesn't seem to work much better though http://pastebin.com/iztTJpjT

Comment: Well with array_filter() you shouldn't be unsetting within the closure, simply returning a boolean true/false to indicate whether the record should be unset or not

Comment: Awesome, worked amazingly, +1 and accepted. Will also publish code to show anyone else searching for this the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked in conjunction with the information provided by Mark Baker, thanks Mark.

```
private function strip(array $exceptions)
{
    $this->hosts = array_filter($this->hosts, function ($k) USE ($exceptions)
    {
        foreach ($exceptions AS $exception)
        {
            if (preg_match("/{$exception}/i", strtolower($k)))

                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    return $this;
}
```